# Self-Joins: is there a way to improve the performance of this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, materialized-views

The purpose of all this is to create a lookup table to avoid a self join down the road, which would involve joins for the same data against much bigger data sets.

In this instance a sales order may have one or both of bill to and ship to customer ID.

The tables here are aggregates of data from 5 different servers, differentiated by the box_id. The customer table is ~1.7M rows, and sales_order is ~55M. The end result is ~52M records and takes on average about 80 minutes to run.

The query:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT sog.box_id  ,
    sog.sales_order_id  ,
    cb.cust_id AS bill_to_customer_id  ,
    cb.customer_name AS bill_to_customer_name  ,
    cs.cust_id AS ship_to_customer_id  ,
    cs.customer_name AS ship_to_customer_name 
FROM sales_order sog 
LEFT JOIN customer cb  ON cb.cust_id = sog.bill_to_id   AND cb.box_id = sog.box_id 
LEFT JOIN customer cs  ON cs.cust_id = sog.ship_to_id   AND cs.box_id = sog.box_id
```

The execution plan:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SkjhXspEs

All of this is happening on SQL Server.

I've tried reproducing the bill to and ship to customer sets as CTEs and joining to those, but found no performance benefit.

The only indexes on these tables are the primary keys (which are synthetic IDs). Somewhat curiously the execution plan analyzer is not recommending adding any indexes to either table; it usually wants me to slap indexes on almost everything.

I don't know that there necessarily IS a way to make this run faster, but I am trying to improve my query optimization and have hit the limit of my knowledge. Any insight is much appreciated.

Comment: Your query is performing a table scan of both tables and scannning `Customer` twice. A covering index on `(Cust_Id) include (Customer_Name)` might be beneficial, but ideally you should only hit the table once which you could do with conditional logic in an `outer apply()`.  It would be better to have the *actual* plan rather than the *estimated* plan in order to determine where the biggest cost is. Do you need the *distinct*?

Comment: Also what is the `@@version`? this query could ideally benefit from *batch mode*

Comment: "takes on average about 80 minutes to run" - where? If you are returning ~52M records to the client then you may be seeing a load of waits as that isn't keeping up. 80 minutes to do three table scans of only moderately large tables and some hash joins certainly seems unexpectedly slow otherwise...

Comment: What does the XML for the actual execution plan. Not estimated. Look like? (this will have details of wait stats encountered and per operator timings plus any spills)

Answer (score 1):

When you run queries like yours -- queries with no WHERE filters -- often the DBMS decides it has to scan entire tables. (In SQL Server execution plans, "clustered index scan" means it is scanning the whole table.) It certainly has to wrangle all the data in the tables. The lookup table you want to create is often called a "materialized view." (An [online version of SQL server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-materialized-view-as-select-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest) has built in support for materialized views, but other versions still don't.)

Depending on how you will use your data, you may be better off avoiding this materialized lookup table. If all your uses of your proposed lookup table involve filtering out a small subset of rows using WHERE clauses, an ordinary non-materialized view may be a good choice. When you give queries involving ordinary views, the query planner folds those views into the query, and may recommend helpful indexes.